# why groupby does not work before i write dataframe to csv?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have problem with "groupby" method, which works just fine in Pandas 1.1.5 and has problems in Pandas 1.3.2 (or i am doing something wrong). Please take a look at the code:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

wallet = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Data','Ticker','Cost','Qty'])
  
if __name__=="__main__":
   
    to_add=['17022019','pcr',10,10]
    a_series = pd.Series(to_add, index = wallet.columns)
    wallet = wallet.append(a_series, ignore_index=True)

    to_add=['12042020','pcr',12,15]
    a_series = pd.Series(to_add, index = wallet.columns)
    wallet = wallet.append(a_series, ignore_index=True)

    to_add=['19012021','peo',8,16]
    a_series = pd.Series(to_add, index = wallet.columns)
    wallet = wallet.append(a_series, ignore_index=True)

    #wallet.to_csv('tmp.csv', sep = ';', encoding =  "ISO-8859-2",index=False)
    #wallet = pd.read_csv('tmp.csv', sep = ';', encoding =  "ISO-8859-2")
    #os.remove('tmp.csv')

    print(wallet)

    summary = wallet.groupby(['Ticker']).sum()
    summary.reset_index()
    print(summary)
```

Three lines before "print(wallet)" are in comment and lets keep them this way for a moment. Result for this code on Python 3.6.6 and Pandas 1.1.5 looks like that:

```
      Data Ticker Cost Qty
0  17022019    pcr   10  10
1  12042020    pcr   12  15
2  19012021    peo    8  16
                    Data  Cost  Qty
Ticker                             
pcr     1702201912042020    22   25
peo             19012021     8   16
```

So, pretty OK. If i "uncomment"  these three lines, result looks like this:

```
       Data Ticker  Cost  Qty
0  17022019    pcr    10   10
1  12042020    pcr    12   15
2  19012021    peo     8   16
            Data  Cost  Qty
Ticker                     
pcr     29064039    22   25
peo     19012021     8   16
```

Data in summary looks different, but it is OK. The real problem is on Python 3.9.6 and Pandas 1.3.2. With commented lines, output looks like this:

```
Data Ticker Cost Qty
0  17022019    pcr   10  10
1  12042020    pcr   12  15
2  19012021    peo    8  16
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: [pcr, peo]
```

So summary is empty dataframe with indexes only (why??? why does it not work? Is it my mistake, or error in pandas? and why there is difference between pandas 1.1.5 and 1.3.2???)

But when I uncomment  these three commented lines, output looks like this:

```
       Data Ticker  Cost  Qty
0  17022019    pcr    10   10
1  12042020    pcr    12   15
2  19012021    peo     8   16
            Data  Cost  Qty
Ticker                     
pcr     29064039    22   25
peo     19012021     8   16
```

So again, as it should.

Questions are:

- Why output looks differently between pandas 1.1.5 and 1.3.2?
- Why if i just write dataframe to csv on hard-drive and read it again before making groupby on it it works normally, and without that i get result as empty dataframe?
- Is there any other solution than writing it and reading again from hard-drive? maybe i can write it to some buffer in memory??
- Am i doing something wrong with this groupby in pandas 1.3.2? This mechanism has been changed and i do not know about something?

Comment: In both versions your `wallet.dtypes` is `object` in 1.2.0 groupby sum now only handles numeric columns (by default). You'll need to make the columns in `wallet` a numeric type if you would like for sum to produce results or `sum(numeric_only=False)`. [GroupBy.sum](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html)

Comment: Thank you! Yes, now it is working! Thank you very much.